# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key login

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard

I'm having this problem with a simple screen of login. I have searched in stackoverflow and I found some solutions but any works for me.

View Controller only has two UITextfield and one button and I have all connected:

[image]

This is my LoginController.h:

[image]

And here it is where it fails:

[image]

I have added this new controller recently, I mean, the root view was other view before but, finally, I need to log in before that.

The console log:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show code for KeyValueLogin class?

Comment: Here it is: http://i.imgur.com/d860hav.png It is translated from a WSDL with SUDZ, not mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue does not seem to be with the XIB/storyboard. You are trying to set value for a property named `login` in your class `KeyValueLogin`. It seems like this property is not declared in the class.

The API `setValue:forKey:` is defined in [`NSKeyValueCoding` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000471-BABEHECF). The fact that your crash logs suggest,

```
[<KeyValueLogin> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key login
```

Means the property is not found in the class.

Your code should be

```
loginInfo.key    = @"login";
loginInfo.value  = @"guest";
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Should be like

```
loginInfo.key = @"login";
loginInfo.value = @"quest";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the correct method.  That method is declared on every `NSObject` (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)).  Look into Key-Value Observing if you want to know more about what it does.  What you want is this:

```
loginInfo.key = @"login";
loginInfo.value = @"guest";
```

Answer (score 1):

let it be

```
[loginInfo setValue:@"guest"];
```

not

```
[loginInfo setValue:@"guest" forKey:@"login"];
```

as You need to access the property called "value"

what are you doing is you are trying to access property called "login"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to do but if you have let's say properties in your KeyValueLogin class let's say

`@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *login;`

you can access it like

```
loginInfo.login    = @"your login";
```

or

```
[loginInfo setValue:@"your login" forKey:@"login"];
```

You use:

```
[loginInfo setValue:@"guest" forKey:@"login"];
```

You have to declare property login in your KeyValueLogin to do that.

Is it something you are after?

Answer (score 0):

Please do check which .xib file your try to load in

> initWithNibName

procedure.

If you did copy & past from other source it is usual problem.